# Pasing string parameter with whitespaces to string command in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am trying to pass a String parameter with whitespaces to a shell command in jenkins but it doesnt work

String parameter name:

```
TAGS
```

My parameter:

```
not @notReady
```

My command:

```
./gradlew -DENV=acceptance -Dcucumber.options='--tags "'$TAGS'" --threads '$THREADS' ' clean test --info
```

Jenkins console:

```
+ ./gradlew -DENV=acceptance '-Dcucumber.options=--tags not' '@notReady --threads 1 ' clean test --info
```

Comment: Do you use a freestyle job or a pipeline?

Comment: only freestyle job with one command bash

Comment: To be honest all those quotes and apostrophes are quite confusing... what if you try to escape the quotes? `./gradlew -DENV=acceptance '-Dcucumber.options=--tags \"$TAGS\" --threads 1 ' clean test --info`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
./gradlew -DENV=acceptance \
  -Dcucumber.options='--tags "'$TAGS'" --threads '$THREADS' '  \
  clean test \
  --info
```

To this:

```
./gradlew -DENV=acceptance \
  -Dcucumber.options='--tags "'"${TAGS}"'" --threads '"${THREADS}"' ' \
  clean test \
  --info
```

...that is, double-quote the strings to preserve any spacing.